# Finding element using jquery which is hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="section project-billing funding-type" style="display: none;" ;>
...
</div>
```

I want to select this element, I tried the same in jquery:

```
$("div[class='section project-billing funding-type']")
```

its returning only

```
[]
```

not the element. Why?

Where I'm making mistake? Is this something to do with hidden?

Comment: are you sure `$` is referring to jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class selectors instead of using attribute equals selector

```
$("div.section.project-billing.funding-type")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **code is working** and returning the element, in fact jQuery function is **returning the collection** and your element is at index one, *jQuery will get the element if it is hidden or visible*.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjfxH/)**

```
$("div[class='section project-billing funding-type']")
```

You should use the class selector instead of attribute selector here.

```
$("div.section.project-billing.funding-type")
```

Comment: Please dont encourage attribute selector in this context. since class selector is performance wise a better one.

Comment: Thanks, I told him about the problem and about to tell him for using the class selector here.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **css()** in jquery.

```
var checkHidden = $("div.section.project-billing.funding-type").css('display');

    alert(checkHidden); // returns 'none' or 'block'
```

or

```
use is() in jquery.

$("div.section.project-billing.funding-type").is(":hidden"); // return true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector:

```
$( "div.section.project-billing.funding-type:hidden")
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbGYF/)**